# Unwind segue for interactive popviewcontroller guesture

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, unwind-segue

For starter - I use Swift 3 and Xcode 8.

I am familiar with possibilities, how to do "unwind segue" from StoryBoards or programmatically ( for example, on UIButton click ).
But I'm interested, is there a possibility to use "unwind segue" for "interactive popviewcontroller" guesture?

By the "interactive popviewcontroller" guesture - I meant the option to dismiss / pop currently pushed UIViewController by swiping screen from left side to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your question is quite easy actually because it seems you are familiar with how to hook up buttons and use them to "unwind segues" as you named it or dismiss view controllers etc. What you can do is get a Swipe Gesture Recognizer from the object library.

[image: /Users/deyanaleksandrov/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-07-03 at 12.12.49 PM.png]

Or a Screen edge Pan Gesture Recognizer (whichever works for you).

[image]

Add that recognizer to your VC in a storyboard and hook it up just like you hook up a UIButton.
Also, note that in the attributes inspector there are properties you can play with and set up the direction of the swipe, the number of touches needed, etc.

[image]
[image]

Check out the next pictures to see the rest of the implementations to handle:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thank you Dido for your response.
This should do the trick and adding some extra transitional animations to it, it would work great! Thank you again! :)

But isn't there any generic possibility to interact with native interactive pop view controller gesture, which is added by default?

Comment: When you embed your VCs in a navigation controller, you can something like what you are looking for but not the same. Generally, you do get for free a back button and the swipe from left to right gesture which brings you back to the previous VC. I guess you know what I am talking about, you must have come across a tutorial about navigation controllers, etc. Other than that, I am pretty certain there is nothing else in Swift that would do what you are asking for. You can either do it with storyboards like I showed you or programmatically(a bit more verbose). Nothing else I can think of though.

Comment: Yes, it seems that you are right, I have searched a lot for something generic, but didn't found nothing. Your solution works great! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I am glad I helped!